# Define fixed coordinate starting point on an "infinite" map

Tags: java

Working on 2d top-down tile map game - I've been looking into generating map coordinates (x/y) that the player can use to navigate the ("infinite", perlin/other-generated terrain) map, and to fix an issue with the noise generation.

I've seen solutions and have been told to translate world coords to screen coords and vice versa - but I'm unable to figure out how you can properly define fixed map coordinates because rendering something on the screen is done with coordinates relative to the frame/pane... so 0,0 is always the top-left of the window, no matter where the map is.

I could easily calculate coordinates for the map (there are `a` tile columns and `b` tile rows between your character's location and the map center ) but **I can't understand how to define a fixed-on-map starting location**? The player may start the game in different locations once I enable a save feature so it can't be based off of that.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is with the start location.

Comment: (assuming the player is always centered on the screen) You can take world coordinates in a box around the player; player is at x,y in the world, map x-10 thru x+10 to the screen and y-10 and y+10 to the screen. (x-10, y-10) being your 0,0 screen coordinates?

Comment: I don't have save functionality yet, but when I do the player will be able to *start* at the last location they quit at - if I use that as a basis for the map coordinates, the map coords will change every time the player starts the game again after having saved/quit while in a different area.

Answer (score 0):

When doing something like this, all coordinates should be in "world coordinates". So your player location is where it's on the infinite map, not where he is on the screen.

To render everything, you need a method that takes world coordinates and transforms them into screen coordinates and vice versa.

To start rendering, use the screen coordinate 0,0 -> transform to world coordinate to get the tile to render in the top left corner. Same with clicking something: Take mouse coordinates, convert, and then look on the world map what's there.

When moving the player, update it's world coordinate, etc.

Comment: This makes sense, but my issue is how do I determine what world coordinate the player is at if I have no point of reference? Rendering the icons uses screen coords, positioning the players requires world coordinates, world coordinates need a starting point of 0,0. How do I set a location or know where 0,0 would be?

Comment: The world's origin is where you put it. Since you use generated terrain, your algorithm will need world coordinates as input. Usually, the algorithm will have specific needs and a certain coordinate will make everything easier. Use that one.